# Unable to enter text in EditText after using setFocusable(true);

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-edittext, android-button

In my application, I have a EditText and a Button. When I press the button, the text entered in EditText is taken into a string and further used for AsyncTask. In the button's onClick method, I've set `et.setFocusable(false)` so that user should not change the text during the AsyncTask. And in the `onPostExecute()` method again I've changed it to `et.setFocusable(true)`. For some unknown reasons i'm able to disable focus from EditText but cannot regain it after AsyncTask completion. Also `bt.setEnabled(false)` is also not working. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Did not post the completed code because I thought it wouldn't be much necessary.

Comment: at least bt.setEnabled should work in every conditions

Comment: try to disable the edit text et.setenable(false);

Answer (score 0):

et.setFocusable(true) is not gonna solve your problem.u need to set setFocusableInTouchMode to true.Code

```
et.setFocusable(true);
et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
et.requestFocus();
```

For more clearfication.Check out this link:[How to setFocusable true after setting it to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39936642/how-to-setfocusable-true-after-setting-it-to-false)