# How to setFocusable true after setting it to false?

Tags: android, android-edittext, focusable

here is my code:

```
 mEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                mEditText.setFocusable(false);
                mEditText.setCursorVisible(false);
         }
});
```

Now i want to enter some text into edittext.for which i have to setFocuable to true.i already tried to setFocusable(true) in onClick , setOnClickListener , setOnTouchListener but nothing is working...help me guys;(...

Comment: can any other one help me....this problem consumed my half of my day??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after searching for hours.i came up with solution-
Xml Code:

```
<EditText
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/et"
android:setFocusable="false"
android:onClick="myFunction"/>
```

Put this java code inside your java file:

```
public void myFuction(View v){
et.setFocusable(true);
et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
et.requestFocus();

}
```

Comment: you should mark your answer as correct if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Programatically

```
    edittext.requestFocus();
```

XML

```
<EditText...>
   <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: can u tell me where to put it exactly.....beacause i tried to put inside setOnKeyListener but it didnt work....